# e.target.result working only after two or three attempts?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to resize an image in the client side and then send it to my server. But the image is not all the times settled correctly to the canvas used to resize the image.

I already sent the image resize but i need to send it at least 2 times to work.
I put `<p>` labels in my html to verify the data of the image and i can see the data incomplete the first time i send it.

This is my html

```js
function ResizeImage() {
  var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('imageFile').files;
  var file = filesToUpload[0];
  console.log('Data');

  // Create an image
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  // Create a file reader
  var reader = new FileReader();
  // Set the image once loaded into file reader
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    //HERE IN THIS PART, the e.target.result works strange
    img.src = e.target.result;

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    //var canvas = $("<canvas>", {"id":"testing"})[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
    // var MAX_HEIGHT = 400;
    var width = 200;
    var height = 200;

    if (img.width > img.height) {
      if (img.width > width) {
        height *= height / img.width;
        //width = width;
      }
    } else {
      if (img.height > height) {
        width *= height / img.height;
        //height = height;
      }
    }
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    console.log(dataurl);
    canvas.toBlob((blob) => {

      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("name", "paul");
      fd.append("image", blob);
      fd.append("key", "××××××××××××");
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:5000/2");
      xhr.send(fd);

    }, "image/png", 1)

    document.getElementById('output').src = dataurl;

    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(dataurl);
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("contenedor");
    element.appendChild(para);

  }
  // Load files into file reader
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fileName">
<input type="file" id="imageFile" name="sampleFile" accept="image/png" />
<input type='button' value='Upload!' onclick="ResizeImage()" />
<img src="" id="output">
<div id="contenedor"></div>
<hr>
```

I expect it works the first time i send the data to the server.

Comment: You should probably move most of your code into the `img.onload` handler

Comment: @Phil, yes, that was the solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Img.src is asynchronous.

To verify this, replace 'img.src = e.target.result;' with

```
img.onload = function () { console.log('done')} 
img.src = e.target.result;
console.log('src')
```

If done runs after src, you know that the image isn't loaded yet when you try to ctx.drawImage.

To fix, simply move all your resizing code into img.onload.